# Reading variable in prolog multible times

Tags: prolog

I want to write a simple game with prolog (Connect four). I want to read input from user many times, the input is a column number.
when I read 'Col' for the second time and I enter different values it crashes and gives false (I know how to read many times):

```
:- dynamic state/3.
:- dynamic top/2.

%% the problem is in the read here
play(Color, Col) :-
top(Col, Raw) -> addRing(Col, Raw, Color); (assert(top(Col,0)) ,addRing(Col, 0, Color)),
win(X,Y,Winner)
-> (write('Game over, winner is '),write(Winner));
(write('Your turn, column? '), read(Col), write('read column is '), write_ln(Col), play(red,Col)).

addRing(Col, Raw, Color):-
assert(state(Col,Raw,Color)),
Next is Raw + 1, retract(top(Col, Raw)), assert(top(Col, Next)).
win(X,Y, Winner) :-
state(X,Y, Color), N1 is X - 1, state(N1, Y, Color), N2 is N1 - 1, state(N2, Y, Color), N3 is N2 - 1, state(N3, Y, Color), Winner = Color.

%% the reset is some methods to determine the winner
win(X,Y, Winner) :-
state(X,Y, Color), N1 is Y - 1, state(X, N1, Color), N2 is N1 - 1, state(X,N2, Color), N3 is N2 - 1, state(X, N3, Color), Winner = Color.

win(X,Y, Winner) :-
state(X,Y, Color),
N1 is X + 1, M1 is Y + 1, state(N1, M1, Color),
N2 is N1 + 1, M2 is M1 + 1, state(N2, M2, Color),
N3 is N2 + 1, M3 is M2 + 1, state(N3, M3, Color),
Winner = Color.

win(X,Y, Winner) :-
state(X,Y, Color),
N1 is X + 1, M1 is Y - 1, state(N1, M1, Color),
N2 is N1 + 1, M2 is M1 - 1, state(N2, M2, Color),
N3 is N2 + 1, M3 is M2 - 1, state(N3, M3, Color),
Winner = Color.
```

To test the game you can start it by calling `play(Red,0)` for example, then it will ask for column number.

Comment: I tested your code, but what you want it to do isn't very clear. play(Red, 0) finishes after you enter a number, and then what?

Comment: @Junuxx, There was a semicolon after the read that made it finish, it should continue to ask you to play another turn, and when you enter column other than 0, it crashes (0 is the value saved in 'Col', that's the problem) I need it to read different inputs from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `Col` in the recursive call should be `Col1`, i.e., not the same variable as in the head.

Comment: @Alexnder, But I had another problem:
reading the same input twice gives True
like if I enter two zeros, it gives me True witch will stop exaction.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. May be you can rephrase it and post as a separate question?